# Is this set the Power Set of Natural Numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a school problem and one of the affirmations I have to prove about it seems -to me- contradictory to what my intuition says.

> Let $Q_n:\{m \in \mathbb{N}: m>n\}$ and $P_n$ the family of all subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$. Let us define
>
> $L_n=\{L:L \in P_n \enspace or \enspace L=P \cup Q_n, P \in P_n\}.$

My intuition tells me that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}L_n=P[\mathbb{N}]$. Where $P[\mathbb{N}]$ is the Power Set of Natural Numbers.

Am I right about this?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I already corrected that. I am writing from my mobile and it's a bit hard.

Comment: The set of even natural numbers is an element of the power set.  Is this an element of your set?

Comment: Your set includes finite subsets, and cofinite subsets; does it include infinite sets with infinite complements?

Comment: This is what I don't completely understand. $P_n$, by definition, is the Power Set of the finite set $\{1,...,n\}$. By $\cup_{n=1}^\infty P_n$ doesn't this become the Power Set of Natural numbers by gathering all of the subsets of the set \{1,...,n\} when $n \rightarrow \infty$ that leads to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: No, it doesn't, because for every $n$ each element of $P_n$ is always finite.  In your union you will have the set of the first $n$ even natural numbers for any finite value of $n$ that you wish, however large., but you will never have the set of *all* even natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $n$, every set in $L_n$ will either be finite or will include every natural number greater than $n$.

Every set then in $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty L_n$ will either be finite or will have some value of $n$ for which every natural number greater than $n$ appears.  Remember... $A\in \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty L_n$ is true if and only if there exists some $n$ for which $A\in L_n$.

As such, the set of even natural numbers is *not* in your set as it is neither finite nor has a value $n$ for which every number greater than $n$ appears in it.